# How to manage theme, plugin and core changes in a Dockerised WordPress instance?

Tags: php, wordpress, git, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm fairly new to Docker and have problems understanding the "hows'".

**Goal**: To set up a WordPress blog using Amazon Elastic container service with a custom theme of my own.

**Steps**:

1. On ECS, Set up a 'WordPress' service
2. Which runs two linked containers - WordPress & MySQL
3. Each of this container has one mounted volume from the host (AWS EFS) - one which enables me to persist DB data (name: *wp-db*), and the other to persist WordPress app data (name: *wp-app*).
4. To be able to create and modify custom themes - I did a git init in the *wp-app* volume and pushed it to a private Git repository.
5. On my local machine - using Docker - I replicated the container environment and cloned the *wp-app* repository into the local host volume.
6. Added a new custom theme and pushed it and pulled it onto my ECS instance.

**Quiestions**:

1. Although this works, is this how one deploys UI and application changes?
2. I have file permission errors after I did a git pull on the ECS volume. (Unable to write by *webserver* into *wp-contents* during upload media). How are the folder permissions affected after a git pull?

Comment: I think you're essentially asking how to manage plugin, core and theme changes. Personally I think it should all live in the WP image - when an upgrade becomes available, do a rebuild, generate your image, get the image onto your server, and stop and start your container.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you do not update the data within a container dynamically. The Docker image is built as a complete image with all its dependencies - server software, application code etc.

The typical workflow for ECS is to push your containers to the Elastic Container Registry (ECR) and then update your Task Definition to use that new image. This triggers the containers to update with the new image.

Comment: Does this mean I've to create a new image every time I fix something in my code - and then create a new task revision - then update my service to use the new task revision?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. This allows the container image to be stateless which will allow you to scale it out without having to worry about code being out of sync or each system OS not being in sync.